# how can I autostart stardict in Background every time when system startup

Tags: linux, dictionary

I am new on linux .I want to autostart the stardict in background progress.In this way ,I can translate words easily by selecting them .
English is not my native tongue,but I love it.

what I do now is just add `stardict &` in /etc/rc.local file as what i did for goagent.but i doesn't work for stardict.

[image]

what should i do?

Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this article they suggest to start startidct as the user logins to GUI mode  http://filosofie.unibuc.ro/~solcan/wt/gnu/s/stardict.html this might be helpful.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: ok,It works.Thanks very much.
you can't image how happy i was!